# ng serve broken: webpack

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I created a new angular2 app with ng new, but on ng serve I get:

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema...
```

googled a lot and uninstalled/installed several times offending packages with no result. I want to UNDERSTAND this, in order to solve it, rather than applying recipes.

ng version is

```
Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
Visit http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.14
node: 7.4.0
os: darwin x64
```

npm list --depth=0

```
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.0.0
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@2.0.0
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.0.0
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser@2.0.0

npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/common@2.4.9, required by @angular/platform-server@2.4.9
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/compiler@2.0.2, required by @angular/compiler-cli@0.6.4
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/compiler@2.4.9, required by @angular/platform-server@2.4.9
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@2.0.2, required by @angular/compiler-cli@0.6.4
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@2.4.9, required by @angular/platform-server@2.4.9
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/platform-browser@2.4.9, required by @angular/platform-server@2.4.9
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/platform-server@2.0.2, required by @angular/compiler-cli@0.6.4
```

I tried several times to un/in/stall UNMEET PEER DEPENDENCY manually, nothing changed.
I have locally:

├── webpack@2.2.0

├── webpack-dev-server@2.2.0

First time with npm, no experience...any suggestion welcome

I've followed https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2234
giving

```
npm uninstall webpack --save-dev
npm install webpack@2.1.0-beta.22 --save-dev
```

and now I get

```
ng serve
** NG Live Development Server is running on http://localhost:4200. **
webpack.validateSchema is not a function
TypeError: webpack.validateSchema is not a function
```

and server goes down

Comment: is it the above posted 3 lines are the only output of `ng version` ?

Comment: @5313M there is also the line about "could not start the watchman..." that I added now. Nothing else

Comment: are you using `ember-cli` ?

Comment: @5313M...no idea! If I understand it fell back on NodeWatcher, for me is fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest building a "new" Angular 2 app on a recent `angular-cli` version instead of the `1.0.0-beta.14`. There has been a `RC` version already.

Comment: @Glasnhost: Yea, updating/refreshing `node_modules/` helps. However, you should base your App on a more recent version of the CLI. There were many API changes which could be avoided.